# Protecting from sun when taking pictures

Tags: equipment-protection, landscape

I've read that taking picture of the sun without protection is a recipe for trouble both for the lens and for the shooter's eyes...

I took this kind of picture this morning, do you think it's necessary to protect even on those kind of picture ?

[image]

If yes, what are the options available to me ?

Comment: Erm yes and no... Actually I'm not pointing at the sun... It's a sun rise and I was just asking myself if I could take that kind of picture or not ?

Comment: Then maybe [this one](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/45126/9161) or [this question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/46390/9161)? I feel that searching this site very similar questions and answers are already present. Could you maybe point out what the linked answers lack for your situation?

Comment: I would happily take a photo like that and have taken many similar. **BUT** carefully read the other answers and general TECHNICAL comments and understand what you are trying to avoid. Note the melted spot in another answer's sample photo. Keep the sun small. Be quick. Be prepared to accept damage worst case. Realise that you have a maximum of 2 eyes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends manly for the overall time your sensor collect light, and how much light it collects so even from the type of your zoom and optics. Bridge and "point and shot" camera expose sensor to light even when you are only pointing at your object. Reflex only during the exposition time.

Focus the light with big zoom over the sun can make damage in my opinion in this case there are no many possibility to damage your sensor.

Of course using UV0 filter or polarizer filter reduce the amount of light collected by the optics so they can help you to save your sensor and channels filter from excessive heat and light degradation but of course if you take a very long exposition time they are useless.