# How to film a eclipse of the sun with a phone cam?

Tags: camera-basics, camera-settings, smartphone, sun, eclipse

as you can read in the title I want to make a photo and a video from a solar eclipse. It should be very simple, fast and cheap, cause in 12 hours after I post this is the eclipse. I have only a Galaxy note 2 and galaxy note one as camera. Also it does not have to be a high quality record but I would like to film with the best quality as possible. So what do I need? What simple stuff could help me? Notice that I don't have any experience or knowledge about photography.

Comment: DID IT WORK??!!

Comment: Actually that's not bad, but you needed a much darker filter for sure. You gave it a try, and that's what is important! My video of the eclipse is terrible, but I was out there, in a good location, giving it my best with the stuff I had at the time. Next time I'll be more ready! I've tried three times to photograph a lunar eclipse, with good equipment, and failed every time. I've spent six or seven hours staring at the moon and I'm a better photographer because of it, even though I didn't get my amazing eclipse shot.

Answer (score 1):

Use an unexposed and developed roll of film as a filter. It won't be great. The problem is the camera, this filter is legit. Here's an example of what you might get...

Eclipse 2012 Behind Clouds (Colorado, USA): https://youtu.be/QkbIn0e8_Rs

You can also use a welding shield but trying to buy a permanent one right before an eclipse is impossible. The auto-darkening ones won't really work.

NOTE: The total solar eclipse of 2015 is not visible from North America.

See the answer here: [Is it dangerous to take pictures of the sun without any filter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/45126/is-it-dangerous-to-take-pictures-of-the-sun-without-any-filter?rq=1)

This can be VERY DANGEROUS for your camera!

Comment: I mean actual camera film. I used 35mm negatives for the video. I just bought the film and had them throw it directly into the machine, to develop the "darkest" negative possible. No prints are needed, only the negatives. Sunglasses are no where near dark enough. The problem with photographing an eclipse is that you'll focus an image of the sun onto your sensor. That's how we used to burn ants when I was kid. It WILL BURN YOUR SENSOR, and permanently damage your camera, if the light isn't filtered a lot.

Comment: If you damage it though, you won't be able to take any pictures. A photo of your sensor burning up isn't going to be interesting in any way. If you manage to get some good shots, please post them here.

Comment: Only when it's aimed at the sun. With the filter, that's all you'll be able to see. The video shows that. Just tape it over the lense.

Answer (score -1):

Try the 'selfie pose' on your smartphone when you take a picture of the eclipse. It is a safe way to look at the sun and it won't damage the camera. ;)